# Can I safely remove/reattach the back of a fitted wardrobe?

Tags: electrical, uk, storage

I've recently gotten a new flat, and the second room has fitted wardrobes along one wall (e.g second picture). I would like to put a TV and playstation in one of these as I don't need the storage space. However, the only accessible plugs are on the opposite wall of the room.

[image: Fitted wardrobe]

Along the opposite side-with the wardrobes- I do not know, but I suspect there could be a mains socket or several behind the wardrobes somewhere.

I would like to unscrew a fitted wardrobe from the wall (two screws along the top, below) to check for a plug, and if it is there, I will make a small hole in the back panel for mains access.

[image: Wardrobe interior]

**Can/Should I do this, would it be safe and will I be able to screw the wardrobe back into the wall (i.e through original holes)?**

Alternatively, if you have a better suggestion for what I could do, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 2):

It is probably safe, but I don't believe that you need to remove the screws. If you loosen the left screw on the L-bracket (the screw into the wall), it appears that the smaller piece with the keyhole will slide up.

Before I moved anything, I would take a step-stool, a flashlight, and a mirror, and see if I could see down the crack in the back. Maybe you can see where the outlet(s) are.

You might want to remove the doors before you move them. It will make them lighter and also less likely to damage something.

Finally, someone more familiar with the electrical code will need to help to decide how big the hole needs to be. It will probably depend on whether the wardrobes are considered to be "built-in" or if they are freestanding furniture that are screwed to the wall for safety. If they are considered to be built-in, recessing is often not allowed. Please add your country tag.

Comment: I hope someone from the UK will chime in, but I sincerely doubt that a cabinet like that would be considered a 'built in' just because it has a couple of screws tying it to the wall. Tip: put a line of tape on the wall beside the wardrobe before you move it. That way, you'll have an accurate way to measure how far in to cut for the mains plug.